# How do I solve this MIT problem to find the months required to buy a house

Tags: python, while-loop

I just picked up coding for the first time and started with the MIT free intro to python course. I am on the first problem of the second homework and I am having a hard time figuring out how to solve. I saw some other posts about this but I think it would be way easier to learn if someone could show me how to do it with my code rather than anothers.

This is the problem:

> You have graduated from MIT and now have a great job! You move to the
> San Francisco Bay Area and decide that you want to start saving to buy
> a house.  As housing prices are very high in the Bay Area, you realize
> you are going to have to save for several years before you can afford
> to make the down payment on a house. In Part A, we are going to
> determine how long it will take you to save enough money to make the
> down payment given the following assumptions:
>
> 1. Call the cost of your dream home total_cost.
> 2. Call the portion of the cost needed for a down payment portion_down_payment. For simplicity, assume that portion_down_payment
>    = 0.25 (25%).
> 3. Call the amount that you have saved thus far current_savings. You start with a current savings of $0.
> 4. Assume that you invest your current savings wisely, with an annual return of r (in other words, at the end of each month, you receive an
>    additional current_savings*r/12 funds to put into your savings – the
>    12 is because r is an annual rate). Assume that your investments earn
>    a  return of r = 0.04 (4%).
> 5. Assume your annual salary is annual_salary.
> 6. Assume you are going to dedicate a certain amount of your salary each month to saving for  the down payment. Call that portion_saved.
>    This variable should be in decimal form (i.e. 0.1 for 10%).
> 7. At the end of each month, your savings will be increased by the return on your investment, plus a percentage of your monthly salary
>    (annual salary / 12). Write a program to calculate how many months it
>    will take you to save up enough money for a down payment. You will
>    want your main variables to be floats, so you should cast user inputs
>    to floats.

Here is my code so far:

```
    total_cost = float(input("What is the cost of the home? "))
annual_salary = float(input("What is your annual salary? "))
portion_saved = float(input("How much would you like to save per year? "))

portion_down = (total_cost*.25)
current_savings = 0
monthly_salary = (annual_salary/12)
interest_rate = .04

#goal is to loop up until I have enough for the down payment




print (total_cost)
print (annual_salary)
print (portion_saved)

print ("The downpayment required for this house is", portion_down)

#need to use +=, otherwise you would have to do current saving = current savings + 1 

months = 1 

while current_savings < portion_down:
    current_savings += current_savings*(.4/12)   #monthly interest
    current_savings += portion_saved   #monthly savings
    months += months + 1
    
print ("It will take", months, "months to save the needed down payment of", portion_down)
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you have encountered?

Comment: "_I am on the first problem of the second homework and I am having a hard time figuring out how to solve."_ What specifically are you having a hard time with? As it's written, it sounds like you want us to solve the whole thing for you (which would completely defeat the purpose of working on a problem like this).

Comment: You have this comment: `need to use +=, otherwise you would have to do current saving = current savings + 1`, and then you have this code: `months += months + 1` - you might review the comment and think about if this line of code does what you expect it to do.

Comment: Also, why create the interest_rate variable unless you're planning to use it? `.4` would be 40% in percentage terms right?

Comment: `portion_saved` refers to the fraction of salary saved.  so the 2nd update should be `current_savings += portion_saved * monthly_salary`.

Comment: Yea I just realized all of the stuff wrong with my post. Again, I am a complete newby so I'm sorry!!

Comment: No worries--as they say--"Make mistakes, learn from them, move on".

Comment: Yes exatly thanks Darryl. I think I solved my problem thanks to your comments. My issue was my understanding of a while loop, but after looking at it I realized that I just need to add the salary everymonth and then multiply by the annual percentage divided by 12. After, I just would add a month to the previous number until I hit my goal. Thank you for making me take a second look

Answer (score 0):

You did a pretty good job.
The biggest problem I see in your code is:

```
months += months + 1
```

You need to change it to:

```
months +=1
```

I also made some tweaks in your code, but essentially I kept the same idea:

```
total_cost = float(input("What is the cost of the home? "))
monthly_salary = float(input("What is your monthly salary? "))
#portion_saved = float(input("How much would you like to save per year? "))

portion_down = (total_cost*.25)
current_savings = 0
interest_rate = 0.04
months = 1
portion_saved = 0.1


print ("The downpayment required for this house is", portion_down)



while current_savings < portion_down:
    current_savings += current_savings(interest_rate/12)+portion_saved*monthly_salary
    months +=1

print ("It will take", months, "months to save the needed down payment of",portion_down)
```